# Symfony: Attach class to all widgets using form theming

Tags: symfony, twig

As the title says I'm trying to attach the bootstrap `form-control` class to each generated input or widget as they're called in twig. I'm trying to use form theming to be able to easily make multiple forms that look the same way.
I'm trying it in the same way as I've managed to get it to work with the labels. But because the `form_widget` block is inherited by other blocks (`form_widget_simple` & `form_widget_compound`).

Here's the code that's giving me trouble

```
{% block form_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
<div class="col-sm-10">

{% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-control ')|trim}) %}
{% if compound %}
    {{ block('form_widget_compound') }}
{% else %}
    {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
{% endif %}

</div>
{% endspaceless %} 
{% endblock form_widget %}
```

Also, the `col-sm-10` div is only rendered on widgets that inherit from `form_widget_simple` and not for the compound widgets.

I don't know if I've explained this clearly enough but any help would be very appreciated.

```
{% block form_label %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if label is not sameas(false) %}
        {% if not compound %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if required %}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required ')|trim}) %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if label is empty %}
            {% set label = name|humanize %}
        {% endif %}
        {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' col-sm-2 control-label ')|trim}) %}
<label {% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}" {% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</label>
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_label %}
```

Comment: Do you already use [application-wide customizations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#making-application-wide-customizations)? *in the same way as I've managed to get it to work with the labels* please show the code which do this so we can better help you.

Comment: Just for the form controls, the labels, widgets and the errors. I've posted the label script, I tried doing it in the same way but it seems  that it's overwritten by the twig inheritance. And I don't want to copy paste the same code for every widget because that kind of defeats the purpose, no?

Answer (score 2):

You have to edit the `form_row`block, it will modify both simple and compound widget.

```
{% block form_row -%}
        {{- form_label(form) -}}
        <div class="col-sm-10">
               {{- form_widget(form) -}}
               {{- form_errors(form) -}}
         </div>
{%- endblock form_row %}
```

**EDIT: For the control-form class**

You can add it in the block `widget_attributes`

```
{% block widget_attributes -%}
    {% set class = 'form-control' %}
id="{{ id }}" name="{{ full_name }}"{% if read_only %} readonly="readonly"{% endif %}{% if disabled %} disabled="disabled"{% endif %}{% if required %} required="required"{% endif %}{% if max_length %} maxlength="{{ max_length }}"{% endif %}{% if pattern %} pattern="{{ pattern }}"{% endif %}
    {% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %}{% if attrname in ['placeholder', 'title'] %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue|trans({}, translation_domain) }}" {% elseif  attrname in ['class'] %} {% set class = class ~ ' ' ~ attrvalue %} {% else %}{{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}" {% endif %}{% endfor %}
class="{{ class }}"
{%- endblock widget_attributes %}
```

The last two lines are pretty intense to read, hope you get the picture.

Comment: This question is more than a year old! Upvote for the effort though

Comment: God, though it was 1 month old, hope it will help someone